# Automatically import nested BOMs version numbers in java project

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, maven-bom

I have a parent platform BOM like this:

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
<version>7.0.LTS.9</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Third Party Dependencies Managed Via third-party BOM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>third-party</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.LTS.9</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.LTS.9</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

I am importing it like this in my project:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.LTS.9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

When I am importing api dependency like below, it automatically pulls the version from the imported BOM.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However when I try to do the same for the third party bom, it is not able to pull the version from the imported BOM.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>third-party</artifactId>
        <type>pom</pom>
 </dependency>
```

Error I get is:  Unresolved dependency: 'com.company:third-party:pom:unknown'. Is there a way to pull the version from the BOM which is imported? If not, I think it defeats the purpose of having a BOM in the first place.

Comment: maven works exactly like you expect, and I suggest to not argue with that until you  provide actual pom.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I am not sure what else do you need? Also, not arguing with anything, just trying to understand how maven works and if the version for the dependency can be pulled from the BOM which is imported in dependency injection.

Comment: modern (at least three years old) maven does import managed dependencies recursively, if you are observing another behaviour that means there is something wrong with your poms, which you do not want to provide.